# How do i click on button

Tags: java, android, appium

Hello I am relatively new to appium.

[image: I need to tap on get started button while automating (below pic)]

The problem i am facing here is little strange. I am unable to tap on Get started button, but while manually i can tap on the button.

Following are the details of appium inspector

```
content-desc: 
type: android.widget.RelativeLayout
text: 
index: 0
enabled: true
location: {0, 0}
size: {720, 1184}
checkable: false
checked: false
focusable: false
clickable: false
long-clickable: false
package: com.sample.spark
password: false
resource-id: com.sample.spark:id/rlIntro
scrollable: false
selected: false
xpath: //android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.view.ViewPager[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]
```

Comment: Put clickable to true?

Comment: as @namlik say you should change 'clickable: false' to 'clickable: true'

Comment: @namlik if i was developer I could have changed that one since I am just testing it. Is there any work around to this?

Comment: Not quite sure, i havent used appium before, but if these are the standard settings to create an object, i imagine you can change these settings in the object itself. Search for a method setClickable. Another option might to just add a normal android clicklistener to it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29479885/6270761 This method should work on all view objects.

Comment: BUT if you can't program something or change the settings files, i can't imagine you can make this clickable. As this would mean anyone that tests the app can change programfunctionality. (which is bad).