# Two part query about creating a read-only Android app

Tags: java, android

I am a noob and have no one to help me so please forgive my ignorance. 
1) I have three menus on main activity (three buttons like read, about and info). I used intent for one of the buttons. But how do I redirect the other two buttons to specific activities (view only)

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

2) What widget should I use to display a page of article within an activity? I have used plain text but unable to format it.

Thanks for the kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to implement an onclick listener on each of the buttons.

An example of how to implement it is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29479937/4857127).

2. It depends on what format the article is. If it is already in HTML format. You may use a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) widget.

FYI: You *can* format a normal TextView, but that's probably a little more advanced and better left alone for now.

Comment: Glad it was helpful, if I've answered all the questions. You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have no problem in using same intent to redirect.
2. Try to host that article online, using css and html and then just link that webpage by using web view in your activity.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Kunal.

Comment: My pleasure, +1 if you want

Comment: I did but as I am very new, the website does not seem to consider it.

Comment: Its okay, happy to help.