# Why is (this) used in setOnClickListener()

Tags: java, android, oop, this

Please explain why, in the below code  `(this)` is used as argument to `setOnClickListener()`? I am new in coding if you could explain the total code I would be thankful.

```
public class MainActivity extends Appcomatactivity implements 
        View.OnClickListner {

  Textview textview;
  Button push_me, push_me2;

  protected void onCreate(bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.Layout.activity_main);
    textview = (Textview)findViewById(R.Id.Textview);
    push_me=(Button)findViewById(R.Id.pushmebutton);
    push_me2=(Button)findViewById(R.Id.pushmebutton2);

    // Why does below code use (this) as argument?
    push_me.setOnClickListener(this);
    push_me2.setOnClickListener(this);
  }
  // <...some activity methods...>

  // onclick method defined:
  public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getid()) {
      case R.Id.pushmebutton:
        textview.setText("button 1 clicked");
        break;
      case R.id.pushmebutton2:
        textview.setText("button 2 clicked");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will Help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479647/setonclicklistener-vs-onclicklistener-vs-view-onclicklistener

Comment: By implementing `View.OnClickListener` you are saying that `MainActivity` class can react to `click` events on some component. To make it do so, you have to register the `MainActivity` instance with the view, which is done by setting it into a View using that method.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is (this) used in setonclicklistner

Because your have implemented [**`View.OnClickListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) interface to your activity

**`View.OnClickListener`** Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is clicked.

By using this **`push_me.setOnClickListener(this);`** you have registered click listener to your view

Answer (score 1):

when we don't want to use anonymous class then we use `this` other way is to use anonymous inner class

```
//declaring OnClickListener as an object
private OnClickListener btnClick = new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
};
//passing listener object to button
btn1.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
```

If there are multiple buttons which require same code to be executed on onClick event then you may define listener as an object and pass it to them.